# How can I uninstall and reinstall XAMPP on Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, xampp, reinstall

I just installed [XAMPP beta with PHP 5.3](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-beta.html) on Vista, but installed it in c:\xampp\xampp instead of c:\xampp.

How can I uninstall it and reinstall in the correct directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just be a matter of deleting the xampp directory and reinstalling.

You might need to delete any shortcuts (Start Menu, Desktop, etc) for the uninstall.

Comment: yes it was as easy as that: had to stop apache and mysql services, then deleted most of c:\xampp, got security messages (not authorized to delete), loged off, logged on, deleted the rest under c:\xampp, reinstalled, perfect, thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's an uninstall executable in the Xampp folder. It should do the rest for you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try going to add/remove programs and uninstalling it? When you reinstall just remember to specify the correct folder (ie. C:/xampp). I don't know if you'll have to stop the services or not. I don't think you will, but it will probably ask you to restart when you uninstall.

Comment: nothing under add/remove programs, and that was the problem: I specified "c:\xampp" and it added its own \xampp to it by default which resulted in c:\xampp\xampp.

Answer (score 0):

Just use CCleaner (free version CCleaner.com) tools/uninstall function. Scroll down to xampp and highlight. Click uninstall. It will stop before it deletes the mysql and htdocs folders. Since mine was a test database and did not have any data I wanted to keep I clicked yes to delete everything. You may have to manually delete c:/xampp and your zipped download of xampp if they are present.

Answer (score 0):

Just you can use the XAMP UNISTALL option....! if you can't find it through the folders, just search it using the search option of the startup button which is seem at the leftmost down of the screen